# get a map view for a specific location I choose it latitude&longitude

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to put a map in my activity that shows a specific location by choosing it latitude&longitude I try this code but it doesn't work can anyone tell me why ???

```
    public class conactus extends Activity{
    private GoogleMap map;
    private LatLng myLoc;
    double latitude=34.112924;
    double longitude=35.650288;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connectus);
        MapFragment fm = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fm.getMap();
        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());  

        try {

            List<Address> ad = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude,1);

            if (ad.size() > 0) {
                myLoc = new LatLng(
                        (int) (ad.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                        (int) (ad.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLoc, 14);
                map.animateCamera(update);
            }    
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting.

Comment: refer this one http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-with-gps-and-locationmanager-in-android

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag fragment in map xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Answer (score 0):

first of all try to debug on real device, sometimes gmap do not display in emulators.
Also check if is valid your debug key for map.
Additionally if still are troubles use [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/) guide it is quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `fm.getMap();` to `map = fm.getMap();`